# Using shared element transition and custom animation together

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation, android-transitions

I want to use shared element transition, but in conjunction with that i would also like to have a general cross-fade animation.

Currently i have this code:

```
Transition transition = TransitionInflater.from(getContext()).inflateTransition(R.transition.my_transition);

myFragment.setSharedElementEnterTransition(transition);

getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fade_out, R.anim.fade_in)
        .replace(R.id.content, myFragment).addToBackStack(null)
        .addSharedElement(sharedElement, "price")
        .commit();
```

The problem is that my custom animations are not running. If i remove the the shared element transition the custom animations are working. Is there any way to use them both? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should handle these 2 separately depending on the OS level the app is running on.

Comment: Mike i still want both on Android 5+.

Comment: @WonderCsabo Did you ever figure this out?  I'm trying to do this now